# python - How can I use a dictionary as multiple condition in pandas.query()?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, typeerror

I have **workers** dictionary with names as keys and lists of two dates as values, that form some time interval:

```
workers = {
    'Alan': [dt.date(2017, 1, 15), dt.date(2020, 5, 4)],
    'Ben': [dt.date(2018, 3, 28), dt.date(2021, 5, 7)]
}
```

And also I have **df** dataframe with some events, which one is related to some worker:

```
event_id    person  event_date
1LFDVDX     Alan    2018-10-28
4DLDQVC     Ben     2022-02-01
5PEXVGH     Ben     2019-09-05
9OPCLXD     John    2020-06-15
```

So I'm trying to filter **df** with *query()* using dictionary as multiple condition. Particularly in described case I want to get from **df** all events for Alan with `event_time` between 2017-01-15 and 2020-05-04 and also all events for Ben with `event_time` between 2018-03-28 and 2021-05-07. So expected result should be as below:

```
event_id    worker  event_date
1LFDVDX     Alan    2018-10-28
5PEXVGH     Ben     2019-09-05
```

I was trying next one:

```
df.query('person in @workers and event_date >= @workers[person][0] and event_date <= @workers[person][1]')
```

`But got TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem is in this expression:

```
person in @workers
```

Here `person` is a `Series` that is a not hashable object, which is being searched in the keys of the dictionary. To solve this particular problem you use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin), but that only answers the question partially.

#### Solution

I suggest you do this instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# create a defaultdict to be used in map, is useful for given a default values to NaN
lookup = defaultdict(list, workers)

# create new Series applying the lookup dictionary
person_map = df["person"].map(lookup)

# convert the series to a DataFrame with the same index as df
ran = pd.DataFrame(data=person_map.to_list(), columns=["start", "end"], index=person_map.index)

# use a very clean query
res = df.query("person.isin(@workers) and @ran.start < event_date < @ran.end")

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  event_id person event_date
0  1LFDVDX   Alan 2018-10-28
2  5PEXVGH    Ben 2019-09-05
```

Comment: Curiously `person.isin(@workers)` gives me "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'" and `person in @workers` is what works.

Answer (score 0):

I would add temporary filter columns with join and query on that:

```
df_workers = pd.DataFrame(workers).T.rename(columns={0: 'start', 1: 'end'})
df2 = df.join(df_workers, on='person')
df2.query('event_date >= start and event_date <= end')[df.columns]
```

If your filter dict is small, you can also compose a full explicit query:

```
query = ' or '.join([
    f"(person == '{k}' and event_date >= '{v[0]}' and event_date <= '{v[1]}')"
    for k, v in workers.items()
])
df.query(query)
```